# How does Perl store and execute menu commands?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl. I'm creating a menu drop down on a GUI that updates whenever the GUI is updated.

The GUI is the UI for a tool that executes Perl code, then saves it off so it can be accessed later and continues on to the next set of code. In this menu, I'd like to access the previous sections that have been tested.

I have this looping through the existing sections:

```
# All this is in one subroutine

my $TestNum;
my $SectionNum;

foreach my $key ( @myDirs )
{
   if( $key =~ m/(\d+)\.(\d+)/ )
   {
      $TestNum= $1;
      $SectionNum = $2;

      my $paragraphFile = "$sectionDir/$key/title.paragraph";
      open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $paragraphFile ) or die "Could not open file '$paragraphFile' $!";

      while( my $row = <$fh>)
      {
         $paraTitle = "";
         chomp $row;
         $paraTitle = $row;
      }

      close( $fh );

      $dataMenu->add( 'command',
                      -label => "$TestNum.$SectionNum $paraTitle",
                      -command => sub { scratch( $requestFile, "Request" ); scratch( $resumeFile, "Switch to $TestNum.$SectionNum" ); } );

   }
}
```

Everything that is seen is correct; it's generating the label tag correctly. However, the command always returns the current $TestNum and $SectionNum instead of the numbers on the label. I thought that the single selection on the menu acts as an independent button, so the label and command gets saved to it and doesn't change.

Why is it doing this, and how can I fix it so the command stores earlier data?

Comment: Please show the complete loop

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have added the entire loop

Comment: It looks like `$TestNum` and `$SectionNum` are global variables. You need to pass a copy of these to the closure function `scratch()` or alternatively make the variables local to the loop

Comment: I updated it again. $TestNum and $SectionNum are defined in the subroutine, but they are set within the loop.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Making the variables local to the loop worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From [perldoc perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html):

> Anonymous subroutines act as closures with respect to **my**() variables,
>   that is, variables lexically visible within the current scope. Closure
>   is a notion out of the Lisp world that says if you define an anonymous
>   function in a particular lexical context, it pretends to run in that
>   context even when it's called outside the context.

So if a closure uses a lexical variable defined in its surrounding lexical scope (like `$TestNum` or `$SectNum` in your example), it saves a *reference* to that variable such that it can use it when called later ( and also such that the reference count of the variable is increased and it will not be destroyed before after the anonymous sub is destroyed itself).

The problem with defining `$SectNum` outside the loop is that the reference of the *same* variable `$SectNum` is taken for each closure generated in the `for` loop, and when the `for` loop finished, the variable `$SectNum` will have the value of the last iteration, and later the anonymous subs are called and extract this particular value from their reference to `$SectNum`. On the other hand, if `$SectNum` is declared *within* the loop, a new variable is generated for each iteration and the closures will refer to that particular value.